# Why is the green leaf in the energy settings missing and slider is at 50% again after restart?

Tags: windows-10, energy-saving

I click the battery icon in the taskbar and put the slider to the left.
The icon in the task bar now shows a green leaf.

It looks like this:

[image]

I restart Windows, and the green leaf is gone.
I click the battery icon, and I see that the slider is in the middle and the text says "Balanced".

How do I keep the slider where it was before a restart?

Answer (score 1):

When you move the slider you make a temporary adjustment. When Windows boots, it returns to the configured power setting "Balanced". You can change that by clicking Akkueinstellungen. You'll get a window that looks like this:

[image: Power Options]

I think in German it's "Energieschema" or "Energieoptionen". The currently chosen scheme is "Ausbalanciert", and you can just change it to "Energiesparplan". Ballpark guesses from what I remember encountering German Windows years back :-)

You can change and adjust the settings at will. Just note that changing to Power Saver mode will affect the performance of your system.

Comment: It's a new feature. I just now found [this article](https://themillergroup.com/maximize-battery-life-windows-10-laptop/) explaining what's going on.

Comment: So there is no way to make my "Energiesparplan" show / activate this green leaf?

Comment: So the leaf is supposed to appear to inform you that your battery power has dropped below certain level and Battery Saver is active. You can set the threshold so that it activates at 100% :-D I personally wouldn't, as [it will turn some things off entirely](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/battery-saving-tips-for-windows-a850d64d-ee8e-c8d2-6c75-8ffe6ea3ea99).

Comment: ''Lower screen brightness while in battery saver" is not a new feature, it's been around sine 2016, which was the first version of Windows 10. @SkyCaver - Why do you care about this green leaf, if you are switching your power plan to something other than power saver, then the "green leaf" is no longer applicable.

Comment: I'm referring to that slider and the green leaf. They weren't there last time I've been running Windows on hardware, I think that was 20H2, which makes it a new feature in current version :-)

Comment: @Ramhound It's not applicable only if Power Saver plan already takes things as far as they can go. That's not what Microsoft article indicates.

Comment: @Peregrino69 - I would call a 20H2 feature new considering it's a year old. The "green leaf", is a universal icon, for power saving mode.  It's been around at least a decade.  [The green leaf has shown up in the Task Manager since at least 2018.](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/109216-green-leaf-icon.html)

Comment: I didn't. Feature generally loses "new" status when a new release supersedes the old one. Task manager is irrelevant in the context. @SkyCaver, if the issue is resolved, could you please accept either of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Search for **powercfg.cpl** in the Windows 10 search box and open it. On the left side, click **Create Power plan** and click the **power saver** radio button. Choose your preferred settings and click **Create**. It will automatically change your power settings to your newly created plan, a restart should not affect the power plan.